# call javascript method on tab change

Tags: javascript, html

Currently doing the HTML code to show tabs as can be seen before. I was wondering how I would be able to call a function every time the tab change as the method shows different data. The method is call method `box()` every time the tab changes, as when I click on the next tab the data on the tab dispersers when I got back to that tab, as the data on the tab is added using a partial view in c#

#### Javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tabs div').hide(); // Hide all divs
    $('#tabs div:first').show(); // Show the first div
    $('#tabs ul li:first').addClass('active'); // Set the class for active state

    $('#tabs ul li a').click(function () { // When link is clicked
        $('#tabs ul li').removeClass('active'); // Remove active class from links
        $(this).parent().addClass('active'); //Set parent of clicked link class to active
        var currentTab = $(this).attr('href'); // Set currentTab to value of href attribute
        $('#tabs div').hide(); // Hide all divs
        $(currentTab).show(); // Show div with id equal to variable currentTab
        return false;
    });
});
```

#### HTML Code

```
<div id="tabs" style="margin:0px; padding:0px;">
    <br />
    <ul>
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#tab-1">Google Analytics</a>               
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#tab-2">Facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li class="">
            <a href="#tab-3">YouTube</a>
        </li>
    </ul>   
    <div id="tab1" style="display: block; margin:0px;"></div>
    <div id="tab-2" style="display: none;"></div>
    <div id="tab-3" style="display: none;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: I am create this tab on a dialog once a button is clicked, and when the tab changes the data disappears is there any way of bind the data with the tab at creattion..

Answer (score 3):

Try :

```
$("#tabs").on("click", "li", function(){
  //Your stuff
  //with $(this) is the clicked li
})
```

Comment: where would i change this form

Comment: this still didnt work when i click on the other chart it remove all the data on privous tab

Comment: hmm, it's the aim of tabs... isn't it ?

Comment: Please mark my answer as resolved or edit your post with real answer for futurs askers.